# Symfony 4 - Is there a way to use a script function to set a twig variable?

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I would like to set a prompt box fromjavascript and pass the text entered to my twig attribute msg.

But I don't know how I can pass from my script to my twig.

There is my code for now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PromptMessage() {
        var saisie = prompt("Saisissez votre texte :", "Texte par défaut");
        console.log(saisie);

    }
</script>

{# It works with an hardcode value in twig #}
{% set msg = 'egaezrf' %}

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.href = '{{ path('email_index', {'iduser': onlineorder.iduser.iduser, 'msg': msg}) }}';">Send Email</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: @DarkBee there's more to this question than just the confusion between when which bit of code runs, though that link is of course helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding here. Twig code runs on the server, before the JS gets anywhere near being executed. Once the Twig code has been executed, *then* the resulting page goes to the browser and the JS is executed.

In effect, this question is "how can my code travel back in time"?

I recommend using the Javascript Routing system (https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/generate_url_javascript.html) to generate the url you need in Javascript directly. This looks something like

```js
// JAVASCRIPT
    var url = Routing.generate('email_index', {
        'iduser': iduser,
        'msg': saisie
    });
```

---

Okay, you've asked a follow-up question about how this should all be put together. I'd recommend not using the `onclick` attribute of the button element: it may be what you've done in class but it's considered outdated. Get a reference to your button:

```js
var myButton = document.querySelector("button");
```

Pass the `iduser` value into Javascript (one of the two options):

```js
var iduser = {{ onlineorder.iduser.iduser }}; // if it's an int
var iduser = "{{ onlineorder.iduser.iduser | e('js') }}"; // if it's a string. 
// the e('js') is a Twig function to safely generate Javascript strings, see
// https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html
```

Then use the first code block above to generate `url`.

Finally set the event handler on the button: [(docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

If you have any further issues I'd recommend asking your lecturer/supervisor.

Comment: Ok I understand the first problem. And ... infact this is my first exercice using javascript. I'm not sure of what to do next, do I have to call my function  in the onClick? Does the function have to return the url or something like this ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Tonyto If an answer is helpful, it's appreciated if you accept it (tick mark on the left of the answer). Many thanks!